# Regular user needing to create new directories as another user

Tags: permissions

I'll try to explain this as best as I can. We have a regular Linux user who makes continuous requests to our Sys Admins to transfer files from his home dir to a particular 'tool' directory.  He then is able to run/execute in the said directory (mounted via samba on his PC; permissions in this tool directory is set to `drwxr-sr-x`).  I'm trying to figure out a way (if possible) to allow this user to be able to do this more less on his own w/out submitting requests to our Sys Admins so frequently. There are obvious security reasons (beyond me) why he can't but I'd like to explore any suggestions to minimize this users requests.

example of this user:

user `x`

path - `/abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno`

user x makes request to move files from his home dir to "mno" and unzip etc.(most of the time he also requests to create a new dir to match the tool being copied).
The path `/abc/def/` are owned by 'root' (permission set to `drwxr-xr-x`) and the remainder are owned by a service account (permissions are set to `drwxr-sr-x`).

I don't think changing the permissions on any of these directories is an option. Are there any options if Management is not willing to change any permissions etc? Security is very important.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not a solution, but one thing that might help the sysadmins is to ask the user to provide them with the list of specific commands they need to run. Assuming the user is knowledgeable enough, instead of saying "please move these files there and unzip them" they would say "please run these specific commands". So the sysadmin would just need to paste them into a terminal and be done with it.

Comment: Should we assume that changing the permissions on any of these directories is not an option? Would you be willing to change the group of the relevant directories, make them group-writeable and make the user a member of this group? We need to know what you are willing to change and what you cannot change. How important is security here? Please [edit] your question and clarify this.

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a group, and some deep enough (for security) directory, change it with chmod g+w,+t   but your question doesn't have enough information to determine if there are unacceptable security risks in this.

Comment: [man sudo](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sudo&sektion=8)

Comment: Why does he even need to copy the files to another directory just to execute them?  Why not just let him mount his home dir on his PC?  Or teach him how to set his PATH?